# Eclipse Oxygen - Git Staging NOT Showing File Under Dot Folder

Tags: eclipse, git, staging, eclipse-oxygen

I have a project in **Eclipse Oxygen** that uses **Git**. When a file is created or edited it shows in the **Unstaged Changes** list on the **Git Staging View**. This allows you to drag the file to the **Staged Changes** list and then it can be committed.

I needed to create a folder named **.sti** directly under the project folder and then a folder named **bin** under that, like this:
**project/.sti/bin**

Then I had to create a file called **assemble** in the **.stl/bin** folder.

The problem is that the file called **assemble** does **NOT** show in the **Unstaged Changes** list. Therefore I cannot stage and commit it.

**Is there any way of getting this file to appear?**

I'm sure that the **.sti** folder is the cause of the problem.

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Does the folder `project/`, `project/.sti/` or `project/.sti/bin/`, contain a `.gitignore` file?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I deleted the .gitignore file in the project folder and recreated it. Upon refreshing the project in Project Explorer, the changed file appeared in the Unstaged Changes.

This was rather strange as the original .gitignore did not specify: .sti